# Unexpected Linq Select behaviour

Tags: c#, linq

I have some problems understanding simple Linq query and hope someone could help me understand it.

```
var updatedRecords = connection
                    .Table<AssetCacheTable>()
                    .Where(record => assetIds.Contains(record.id))
                    .Select(record => new AssetCacheTable { id = "", refs = 0 }).ToList();
```

If I check the results, **refs** is not 0, but the original value. Seems somehow counterintuitive and there's probably some rookie mistake here.
This can be fixed by adding ToList()

```
.Where(record => assetIds.Contains(record.id)).ToList()
```

Can someone explain me why do I need to create a copy of the list in Where clause? The way I understand the current Select query, is that a new list is populated with new AssetCacheTable objects, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Definition of AssetCacheTable is here:

```
        public class AssetCacheTable
        {
            [PrimaryKey]
            [NotNull]
            public string id { get; set; }
            public int refs { get; set; }
        }
```

Table<> Definition can be found here https://github.com/robertohuertasm/SQLite4Unity3d/blob/master/Example/Assets/Scripts/SQLite.cs#L813

Thank you.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't have to use ToList(). Keep in mind though, that during the enumeration your source (`connection.Table<AssetCacheTable>`) should not change. Please provide (the relevant parts of) the AssetCacheTable and the type of `connection.Table<AssetCacheTable>`

Comment: Thanks for replying @HaraldCoppoolse. I have updated my question with more details. I hope I have provided all necessary. The queries are synchronous.